My web Call function does not work in OnAppear but it does in Refreshable - SwiftUI
Hi I am making an application that scrapes data from 2 different web, when I call the functions in the .OnAppear method 1 of the two does not work.
But if I call it from the .Refreshable, that is to say making swipeDown, the call to the web works, to what is this due ?
my two functions
-fetchDolar()
-fetchHistorico()
  func fetchDolar() {
           print("Scrapeando datos blue")
            Scrapper.shared.scrappearDolar() {result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isLoading = false
                    
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        self.dolar = data
                        
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self.error = error
                        print("Error\(error)")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
        func fetchHistorico() {
           // print("scrapeando Historico")
            Scrapper.shared.scrapearHistoricoDolar() {result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isLoadingHistorico = false
                    
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let data):
                        print("Entro en el historico")
                        self.historicoDolar = data
                        
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self.error = error
                        print("Error\(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }


Could you show the SxitUI code where you call your functions ?

you say .OnAppear (which should be  .onAppear) does not work, but you don't show the code for that. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code.
